# SurveyMonkey iOS SDK - Survey response error

Tags: ios, surveymonkey

I couldn't handle the survey response in my iOS App. I am getting the following error log,

Error Domain=SurveyMonkeySDK_ServerError Code=5 "(null)" UserInfo={SurveyMonkeySDK_Error=There was a problem retrieving the user's response to this survey., NSUnderlyingError=0x160a40500 {Error Domain=SurveyMonkeySDK_ServerError Code=7 "(null)" UserInfo={SurveyMonkeySDK_Error=Response limit exceeded for your plan. Upgrade to access more responses through the SDK.}}}

May I have a solution to the above issue

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear.  What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Dan.. {SurveyMonkeySDK_Error=Response limit exceeded for your plan. Upgrade to access more responses through the SDK.}}} Though I upgraded  the plan, I am getting this error

Comment: @GovindaKarthikeyan..can you please elaborate me how you are integrating api for getting surveys not feedback.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the engineer from SurveyMonkey who works on the SDK. This is the error message our SDK gives if your account isn't a GOLD account or higher. If you're on a Select plan, you can't parse responses and need to upgrade to gain access to this feature. I'll make sure to update our documentation to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks bleiken. I got it